# Need to check what character at a certain position in a list is

Tags: python, list

I need to see what character is at a specific row and column in a list. I am creating a game and need to prevent the player from fazing through walls.

Here is my code so far.

```
import copy
def print_house(h,sr,sc):
  th = copy.deepcopy(h)
  th[sr][sc] = "@"
  for i in th:
    print(''.join(str(x) for x in i), end='')   
    
def build_house():
    #print("Please enter the house file: ")
    house_file = "house.txt"
    housefp = open(house_file, "r")
    global myhouse
    myhouse = []
    line = housefp.readline()
    while line:
      myhouse.append(list(line))
      line = housefp.readline()
    return myhouse

def check_north(h,sr,sc):
    if sc-1 == "*":
        return False
    else:
        return True
def check_south(h,sr,sc):
    if sr+1 == "*":
        return False
    else:
        return True
def check_east(h,sr,sc):
    if sc+1 == "*":
        return False
    else:
        return True
def check_west(h,sr,sc):
    if sc-1 == "*":
        return False
    else:
        return True



def main():
    global house, startrow, startcol
    house = build_house()
    startrow, startcol = 1,3
    num_treasures = 2
    tcount = 0
    while tcount < num_treasures:
        print_house(myhouse, startrow, startcol)
        print("You can go N,S,W,E")
        command = input("Please enter where to do using the w,a,s,d keys or q to quit:")
        if command == "w" and check_north(myhouse, startrow, startcol) == True:
            trow = startrow-1
            tcol = startcol
        elif command == "a" and check_west(myhouse, startrow, startcol) == True:
            trow = startrow
            tcol = startcol-1
        elif command == "s" and check_south(myhouse, startrow, startcol) == True:
            trow = startrow+1
            tcol = startcol
        elif command == "d" and check_east(myhouse, startrow, startcol) == True:
            trow = startrow
            tcol = startcol+1
        elif command == "q":
            return
        else:
            print("Sorry, you can't go through walls")

        
        startrow,startcol = trow,tcol



main()
```

it also uses a text file with the map here. The text file is named house.txt

```
***************
***       0   ********************************
***                                   6      *
***********   **************************     *
          *   *                         *    *
    ********5***************            *  t *
    *                      *            ******
    *        t         1   *
    ************************
```

Comment: what do you have in this list? Single chars? Lines with many chars? Do you keep it in 1D list or 2D list (nested lists)? Frankly I don't understand what is your problem. I see you use `th[sr][sc]` so you already know how to get char from 2D list. So you can use this to check value - ie. `if th[sr][sc] == "*": ...`

Comment: I think I see where is your problem - you check `if sc-1 == "*":` but you should `get` char in the same way as you `set` char  -  `th[sr][sc]` - so you need `if th[sr][sc-1] == "*":`

Answer (score 0):

If I see correctly you try to check char using `if sc-1 == "*":` but you should `get` char in the same way as you `set` char - using `th[sr][sc]`.

So you need

```
if th[sr][sc-1] == "*":
```

---

So you need

```
def check_north(h, sr, sc):
    if h[sr][sc-1] == "*":
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

If you use `!=` instead of `==` then you will have

```
def check_north(h, sr, sc):
    if h[sr][sc-1] != "*":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

which you can reduce to

```
def check_north(h,sr,sc):
    return h[sr][sc-1] != "*"
```

because comparition `!=` gives result `True` or `False`

Using `==` you would have to add `not` to convert `True` to `False` and `False` to `True`

```
def check_north(h,sr,sc):
    return not (h[sr][sc-1] == "*")
```